# Uncrossing differential pair routing

Tags: pcb-design

I'm routing USB tracks, which are 90R differential impedance from a USB hub to a downstream device, but the D+ and D- pads downstream are crossed over, and the device has an exposed pad, so I can't route behind.  Is there a better way of doing this than my solution (see image) to use vias right at the end of the routing for the smallest distance possible?

[image: diffpair crossed with vias]

Comment: What does this mean: *use vias right at the end of the routing*? Nobody but you can tell which is the start and which is the end.

Comment: that's true, it's the vias shown in the image attached, next to the chip - I define this as the end

Comment: What hole size are those vias? I'd probably want to do the same on both tracks but with smaller vias.

Comment: Vias are quite big 1.3mm / 0.8mm hole, I can go down to 0.8mm/0.4mm vias, is using as small a via as possible best practice for this sort of issue? What's the technical reasoning behind it?

Comment: 0.5mm hole vias please. There won't be problems with those with any decent PCB manufacturer. 0.8mm hole vias are for power electronics. (But even then, placing multiple smaller vias is better than one big one.)

Comment: Also, does your PCB have four layers? Because that won't be 90Ω differential impedance by any chance if the ground layer is more than 0.3mm below the pair.

Comment: Yes, it’s 4-layer, the calculations for impedance are based on a dielectric thickness to the reference plane of 0.32mm as I recall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Vias are quite big 1.3mm / 0.8mm hole, I can go down to 0.8mm/0.4mm
> vias, is using as small a via as possible best practice for this sort
> of issue? What's the technical reasoning behind it?*

Ideally, for high speed balanced signals like USB you should introduce the same to one track as you do on the other. Here's what I mean (roughly): -

[image]

But, make your vias **much** smaller and therefore more likely to be closer to 45 Ω impedance on each. The impedance is determined by various things but, in short, a fat via pad will have an impedance that is too low and you might get some problems. Its impedance will be too low because the inductance to capacitance ratio will be smaller than that dictated by rules: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$

[This site](https://www.polarinstruments.com/support/si/AP8178.html) provides useful information about how you should go about doing this such as this for a couple of example of 50 Ω vias: -

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So you have a couple of examples and given that they are 50 Ω, they are close enough to your required 45 Ω per track for this to be OK in my opinion.